# Is it possible to change datatypes in the mysql dump file of an database?

Tags: mysql, database, sqldatatypes

I have a big MySQL database and have to change some Primary Keys from INT to BIGINT. Is it possible to make a dump and change the datatypes in there, then deploy it back on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar topic on db.stackexchange:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95740/alter-primary-key-column-from-int-to-bigint-in-production-mysql-5-6-19a

Does that help?